# AngularJS: passing $location to constant()

Tags: angularjs

I've the

```
module.constant('name', {
   eventHandler: function(){...},
})
```

that returns map of event handlers. Inside eventHandler function I"d like to use `$location.path('/')` for redirection. How to pass `$location` to `constant`.

Comment: To use dynamic values as constant sounds wrong for me. I recommend to use a service for that

Comment: To double tschiela, it is not only wrong, but also impossible in Angular. Use a service.

Comment: it's not dynamic. It's actually constant. But I can replace with `.value()`. My question remain unanswered.

Comment: Someone could explain me why it's wrong? I've some constant set of eventHandlers that I reuse in my controllers and extend with `angular.extend` when I need it. The base values are unchanged. Service is not good for it as there's no angular's business logic, just plain javascript event handlers.

Comment: You'll never be able to inject `$location` into a constant because that is not how they are designed to be used. There is really no other way to explain that. And a `service` is not reserved for business logic. I'm not sure where you read that. Even the official tutorial on Angular's own homepage uses a service for wrapping a REST call, which is not business logic.